# Does English have this idiom "fire raining/falling from the earth and sky"

Tags: idioms, phrase-request

Suppose you want to describe a war scene. In Persian, there is a phrase like

> There were fire raining/falling from the earth and sky

What is an equivalent in English?

Comment: There **was** fire raining  (singular subject). **rained down** is commonly used to describe ballistic assaults of one sort or another (arrows, bombs, etc).  But it rains down from the sky, not from the earth. It rains down **upon** the earth.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thanks, however in Persian to exaggerate the situation, the fire may rain down from the sky and also from the earth (As there is no direction, they rain down from everywhere).

Comment: I can't think of any English idiom where it "rains" up. There's the prepositional phrase **in all directions**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo yes I am sure, no matter! "from the sky" is sufficient. It just seems English people are more pedantic in their idioms.

Comment: @Ahmad: that wasn't *my* question.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Ooops my bad.  You are correct.  My brain didn't register the **'t** on the end of **can**

Answer (score 1):

The description used in your example could very much be used in English, although the grammatically correct way of saying it would be

> There **was** fire raining from the sky

or

> There **was** fire falling from the sky

I have heard people referring to *"fire rain"* or saying it is *"raining fire"* when talking about burning embers of a large forest fire or building fire falling around the area.

The expression could even refer to hot lava falling during a volcanic explosion or as used in your example to describe [the use of White Phosphorous](https://www.hrw.org/report/2009/03/25/rain-fire/israels-unlawful-use-white-phosphorus-gaza)

[image: White Phosphorous used in Gaza]
(Image Source: [Haaretz](https://www.haaretz.com/1.5211081))